# React native UseEffect and async issue

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to get a `StoreKey` from `firestore (v9)`, and put it inside another collection of DB as a path.
for example, get storeKey (132, for example) and put inside
`collection(db, 'store', storeKey, 'coffeeDB')` to access specific sub collection. I put two function (1: getData (storeKey), 2: access to sub collection) into `UseEffect` so that it can run when it's mounted.
However, I found `UseEffect` runs twice, initial storeKey shows Array [], and the next run gets proper value which is 132. So, I'm having an error due to the first run.
I guess it's because the second function inside `UseEffect` does not wait for getData function to watch the data, but not too sure.
How can I resolve this issue??

```js
    const getData = async(setStoreKey, setName) => {
    console.log('xxxx')
    const auth = getAuth();
    const user = auth.currentUser;
    if(user !== null){
        const email = user.email;
        
        const UserInfo = await getDoc(doc(db, 'users', email));
        if(UserInfo.exists()){
            setStoreKey(UserInfo.data().storeKey)
            setName(UserInfo.data().name);
        }
        else{
            console.log('None')
        }
        return
        
    }
    }
```

T

```js
    const StockScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
    const [storeKey, setStoreKey] = useState([]);
    const [userName, setName] = useState([]);
    const [coffeeStock, setCoffeeStock] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        
        getData(setStoreKey, setName);
        
        const unsub = onSnapshot(collection(db, 'Store', storeKey, 'coffeeDB'), (snapshot) => {
            setCoffeeStock(snapshot.docs.map((doc) =>  ({
                id: doc.id,
                data: doc.data(),
                number: doc.data(),
            })));
        });
        
        return unsub;
    }, [storeKey]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove dependency from second argument in `useEffect` and pass blank array

```
useEffect(() => {
    // your code
}, []);
```

It will run only once when your component is loaded. It is similar to `componentDidMount` of class component.

Comment: thanks for reply! i tried it and it run only once, but storeKey returns empty array, ( Array [ ] when console.log). I'm not sure why it doesn't return proper value

Answer (score 0):

The reason your `useEffect` run twice is because your `storeKey` state changing in `getData(setStoreKey, setName)` function. So what you can do here if you want to call `getData()` function once is to declare it on a separate `useEffect` function like:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    getData(setStoreKey, setName); //call your getData function once
}, []);
```

And what I see is you need to update `StoreKey` every time for the `unsub` listener so with that above `useEffect` call another `useEffect` whenever the `StoreKey` dependency change like:

```js
    useEffect(() => {
        getData(setStoreKey, setName); //call your getData function once
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {        //another useEffect whenever storeKey changes
        const unsub = onSnapshot(collection(db, 'Store', storeKey, 'coffeeDB'), (snapshot) => {
            setCoffeeStock(snapshot.docs.map((doc) =>  ({
                id: doc.id,
                data: doc.data(),
                number: doc.data(),
            })));
        });
        
        return unsub;
    }, [storeKey]);
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: thanks for comment! yep, I tried it, but still having the problem. Im not quite sure why storeKey returns empty array in first run. I should have returned proper value tho